# SNMP segfaults on Ubuntu 10.04 after some time

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, snmpd

Just had snmpd segfault on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS box. snmpd has been running on this system for some time (weeks). There has been a reasonable amount of load, but nothing too extreme for the system.

```
snmpd[1185]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fab8a626167 sp 00007fffef80ac80 error 6 in libnetsnmpmibs.so.15.1.2[7fab8a575000+10f000]
```

Anyone seen this before? Is this a known issue with snmpd? I'm using

snmpd 5.4.2.1~dfsg0ubuntu1-0ubuntu2.1   SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything at a cursory glance.  You could try upgrading if a newer version is available, or possibly run memtest86.